# Python 3 using any() on filter() removes the 1st element

Tags: python-3.x

See below:

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 26 2018, 19:50:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mappings = [1, None, 2, 3, None, 4]
>>> mappings = filter(lambda x: bool(x), mappings)
>>> any(mappings)
True
>>> list(mappings)
[2, 3, 4]
```

vs without `any()`

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 26 2018, 19:50:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
>>> mappings = [1, None, 2, 3, None, 4]
>>> mappings = filter(lambda x: bool(x), mappings)
>>> list(mappings)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> mappings = [1, None, 2, 3, None, 4]
>>> mappings = filter(lambda x: bool(x), mappings)
>>> mappings
<filter object at 0x10eea7f60>
```

Notice that you have an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) rather than a list.

You can view the contents of a list as many times as you like,
and they won't change.
Consuming values from an iterator, OTOH, is destructive, as you found out.

Calling `any()` consumed some but not all of the values.

You would be happier if you saved a copy of the filtered values:

```
>>> mappings = list(filter(lambda x: bool(x), mappings))
>>> mappings
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now you can run it through `any()`, and
make *another* copy with `list()`,
to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems like `filter()` returns a generator or iterator?

```
>>> mappings = [1, None, 2, 3, None, 4]
>>> mappings = filter(lambda x: bool(x), mappings)
>>> mappings
<filter object at 0x1091c2c18>
>>> any(mappings)
True
>>> any(mappings)
True
>>> list(mappings)
[3, 4]
```

If it's an generator/iterator then it makes more sense, if `any()` sees the first element being true and return true, meanwhile consumed the first element from the generator/iterator.